# Facebook Reactions don't automatically Poll Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a reactions script for my live stream that I do via OBS studio. I would like call the api every time someone likes the video stream. I tried set interval and set timeout but they are returning updated values. Any luck on what else I can do to get the api to update live without having to refresh the page?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: true
            });
            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '637146819824957',
                    version: 'v2.8' // or v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, ...
                });


                FB.getLoginStatus(function() {



                    FB.api(
                        '1882331202005446',
                        'GET', {
                            "fields": "comments.order(reverse_chronological),reactions"
                        },

                        function(response) {

                            function showReactions() { 

                            var rValue = response.reactions.data;

                            var reactionCounts = {
                                "LIKE": 0,
                                "LOVE": 0,
                                "WOW": 0,
                                "HAHA": 0,
                                "SAD": 0,
                                "ANGRY": 0
                            };
                            for (var i = 0; i < rValue.length; i++) {
                                var reactionType = rValue[i].type;
                                reactionCounts[reactionType] = reactionCounts[reactionType] + 1;
                            }


                            document.getElementById("like").innerHTML = reactionCounts["LIKE"];
                            document.getElementById("love").innerHTML = reactionCounts["LOVE"];
                            document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML = reactionCounts["HAHA"];
                            document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML = reactionCounts["WOW"];
                            document.getElementById("sad").innerHTML = reactionCounts["SAD"];
                            document.getElementById("angry").innerHTML = reactionCounts["ANGRY"];

                            console.log(reactionCounts);


                                setTimeout(showReactions, 5000);

                            }

                              setTimeout(showReactions, 5000);








                        });


                });

            });


        });
```

Comment: I assume you're getting a syntax error with this...  you have to close the parenthesis from `FB.api()`.  It's hard to tell though, please attempt to format your code.

Comment: @Brad I formatted the code